# How do I get php `json_encode` to return a Javascript array instead of a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an array in PHP which contains a list of objects:

```
// This is a var_dump of $data

array(3911) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#44 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Forest"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#43 (3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(3) "Lt. Dan"
  }

  // etc ...
}
```

I am converting that array into a flat index based array:

```
$return = [];
$length = count($data);
$return = array_fill(0, $length, null);

// Convert list into flat array
foreach ( $data as $item ){
  $return[(int)$item->ID] = $item->name;
}

header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( $return );
```

The result I'm getting with `json_encode` is an object list:

```
{"0":null,"1":"Forest","2":"Lt. Dan","3":"Bubba","4":"Jenny"}
```

What I am expecting to get is:

```
[null,"Forest","Lt. Dan","Bubba","Jenny"]
```

#### How do I get `json_encode` to return a Javascript array instead of a Javascript object?

---

**Side note**: [The Manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes) that:

> When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

But my array is a continous set, that's why I am using `array_fill`.

Comment: Run another line of code?

Comment: Could you add your `$data` object to this post, or at least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: Why array_fill? Why $item->ID when it's just a list? Works here https://3v4l.org/SWhE0

Comment: Why you don't convert it in javascript?

Comment: @copynpaste Read the last line of my question, I'm using array fill because `json_encode` expects the array to be a sequential list and my ID's aren't always sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDs aren't sequential, then `count($data)` is not going to give the results you are looking for. For example, if `$data` has keys 1, 2, 3, and 5; then `array_fill` will only give you keys 0-3 on `$return`, and you'll end up with a non-sequential array.

Try this instead:

```
$return = [];
$length = max(array_keys($data));
$return = array_fill(0, $length, null);
```

Comment: This is not 100% a solution to my issue as I had to get the max ID and not the max index in the first array but you pointed me to the right ally! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**:

To rephrase the problem:

> desired is an array for which indices correspond to IDs of given
>   objects. For every missing ID, the array item at that index must be
>   `null`.

from the provided example, it can be seen that IDs of objects in `$data` are zero indexed, so we initialize and array with a length of `max(ID) + 1` and fill it as you did previously. **However** and IMHO, I think this would be a *misuse* of array data structure. If you have huge gaps in your IDs, your array would contain a big number of `null`s. Since JS doesn't have associative arrays, the best option would be to convert your array into an object (as PHP did in your case).

---

Since `$data` is not given, this is the best what I came up with:

generally `json_encode` returns an object if you have an associative array, otherwise, you'll get a normal JSON array. So you might wanna try something like this:

```php
echo json_encode( array_values($return) );
```

Comment: I added an example of my $data list. array_value won't work because I want to transform the ID into the index of the array.

Comment: This answer was based upon your provided example. You should've mentioned that IDs are not sequential. In that case the answer from @miken32 is the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I did not know my ID's were not sequential and so did not mention it :(

Comment: @hitautodestruct I am updating the answer just for the reference :)

Comment: @hitautodestruct note that you have to have `max(ID) + 1` as array length.